# Why isn't `execlp()` in the system call section

Tags: linux, system-calls, manpage

I noticed that the entry for `execlp()` is not in the system call (2) section of the man pages, but instead resides in section (3), subroutines. Why is this, while `fork()` resides in section (2)?

Here are the links:
https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork
https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `execlp()` (and all the other `execXXX()` functions in the same man page) is a library function wrapper around the [`execve()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call. The steps of collecting the variadic arguments into an array, and searching for the program in the `PATH` environment variable, are done in user-mode code in the library, before calling into the kernel to initiate execution of the program.

`fork()`, on the other hand, simply calls directly into the kernel.